# Could I make a column in a table only allows one 'true' value and all other rows should be 'false'

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, Can I put a restriction like below at database level?

I need to make sure 
1. a specific column can only take either 'true' or 'false' values.
2. and exactly only one row should be having 'true' value?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Rather than having the boolean attribute in the table, you could have another table that contains one row and points to the row in the original table that you consider true.

Changing the true value is a matter of updating the foreign key in the TrueRow table.

Comment: Yep. And it would be possible to use a check constraint to ensure that only one row exists (using Celko's technique here http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/ms-sql-server/3453/How-to-Modify-a-views-SQL-source-from-a-program)

Comment: exactly what I wrote on my comment - but we do not know if it is possible to redesign the SQL-Schema. The problem is definitifly a problem-by-design. Anyway this was already discussed ...

Comment: Thanks Gilbert & Erik. Changing schema is a possibility, so I would go with this approach.

Comment: Definitely a better way of thinking about the problem.

Comment: Seems good but I can't figure out how to join three tables now. It creates something like circular dependency.

Answer (score 15):

In MySQL, a unique index will ignore any `NULL` values. So there's a bit of a hack you could use.

You could consider adding a nullable `bit` column (which can only have the value 1 or 0):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
  ADD COLUMN `is_default` BIT NULL,
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `is_default_UNIQUE` (`is_default` ASC);
```

At this point, one row can be 1 (TRUE), and attempting to add another row that is also TRUE, will result in an error:

```
1062: Duplicate entry '\x01' for key 'is_default_UNIQUE'
```

The only catch is that all other rows need to be `NULL` and cannot be false as that would also count as a unique value.

[image: Example table data]

(This really isn't what indexes are meant to be used for though)

Comment: Great approach. I wouldn't want to add another table and increase number of joins for my query. :)

Comment: instead of `bit` we could use an `enum` which would have just one value eg: `default` this column would be nullable. then you wouldn't have to worry about accidentally inserting any other value other than `null` or `default`

Answer (score 1):

1. a specific column can only take either 'true' or 'false' values.

   Use Datatype for column either `boolean` or `tiny-int`

2  and exactly only one row should be having 'true' value?

you have to write a query which update all the row columns to false except one you set to true

Comment: for (2), I want it to be like constraint (similar to unique, primary key constraints)

Answer (score 1):

Set the data-type of the column to "boolean"; then add a trigger-function, that sets the row you want to be always "true" to true on update.

Comment: Thanks trigger is a good option, but don't we have any other options?

Comment: I don't think so; you cannot set a column-lock on a single row to prevent updates. Any kind of UNIQUE index also won't work, since all other false-entries would throw a duplicate-key-exception. Only if you use stored procedures or views to change the table, you could enforce it there. If the table is used directly, I think the trigger is the one and only option.
Another solution would be to extract the column to another table and join this table then. But I'm not able to check this, cause I do not know what you are exactly doing.

Comment: Triggers are not a way to put constraints on table. Plus there will be multiple inserts at the same time, it would be a lot harder to handle concurrency. Constraints are there to ensure integrity of the Database!