# MySQL: Insert/update multiple rows from one table

Tags: mysql

I have a device system where users are able to select a device and store up to 10 devices on their account. Only one device can be active at any one time.

I am trying to come up with the correct MySQL query to insert/update the below userdevice table based on the users' selected device; adding any new device (as active) if it isn't already on their account, and make any other devices on their account inactive (0).

$userId, $newDeviceId and $oldActiveDeviceId is available to construct the query.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userdevice` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deviceid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateadded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `datelastactive` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`,`deviceid`),
  KEY `active` (`active`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `userdevice` (`userid`, `deviceid`, `dateadded`, `datelastactive`, `active`)         VALUES
(1, 1294, '2013-01-17 02:46:09', '2013-01-17 02:48:00', 1),
(1, 1307, '2013-01-17 02:45:24', '2013-01-17 02:45:00', 0),
(1, 1760, '2013-01-17 02:40:45', '2013-01-17 02:42:00', 0);
```

I came up with the following query, but of course it resets the 'datelastactive' field when updating oldActiveDeviceId:

```
INSERT INTO userdevice
(userid, deviceid, dateadded, datelastactive, active
VALUES
($userId,$newestDeviceId,NOW(),NOW(),1), 
($userId,$oldActiveDeviceId,'','',0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE datelastactive = VALUES(datelastactive), active = VALUES(active)
```

The other problem with this is that it allows two devices to be active.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the datelastactive, change the datelastactive to NOW().

```
INSERT INTO userdevice
    (userid, deviceid, dateadded, datelastactive, active
VALUES
    ($userId,$newestDeviceId,NOW(),NOW(),1), 
    ($userId,$oldActiveDeviceId,'','',0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE datelastactive = NOW(), active = VALUES(active)
```

Single active record:

The best advice for ensuring a single active record would be to keep it in a separate [child record table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228161/could-i-make-a-column-in-a-table-only-allows-one-true-value-and-all-other-rows). This may require that you update your table somewhat. For example, you may need to add an ID as the PK and then set the userid / deviceid as UNIQUE.

Comment: This works, but it updates datelastactive = NOW() on both rows, I only wanted that to be on the row to be active (sorry for being unclear). I replaced this with: datelastactive = IF(VALUES(datelastactive) < datelastactive, datelastactive,VALUES(datelastactive)) and it seems to work. - Thanks