# Can a Postgres constraint limit a table to one true value, but many false values?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have read: [Could I make a column in a table only allows one 'true' value and all other rows should be 'false'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228161/could-i-make-a-column-in-a-table-only-allows-one-true-value-and-all-other-rows) - the same could be made to work in Postgres, but I'd like a one-table solution, if possible.

I have a logon_state table:

```
CREATE TABLE logon_state (
    username VARCHAR(20) references users,
    region region NOT NULL,
    channel channel NOT NULL,
    ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    callsign VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    live BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (username, region, channel)
);
```

How can I add a constraint or unique key such that for each `region`/`channel` combination only one row may have a `live` value of `true` while an unlimited number of rows can have a `live` value of `false`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can be done with a partial unique index:

```
create unique index on logon_state (region, chanel)
  where live;
```

This assumes that the domains (or types) `region` and `chanel` can be compared properly. If those are record types with multiple fields, this will probably not work.

Comment: `region` and `channel` are enums.  Does this break your answer?

Comment: Enums were fine.