# How to join tables that depends on each other

Tags: mysql, database-design, rdbms

Let's say I am making a book lending database.

```
drop table lend_current;
drop table lend_history;
drop table books;

create table books ( id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT);

create table lend_history (
 id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 book_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 lender_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FK_books FOREIGN KEY(book_id) REFERENCES books(id));

create table lend_current (
  lend_history_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_lendhistory FOREIGN KEY(lend_history_id) REFERENCES lend_history(id));

INSERT INTO books (id) VALUE(1);
INSERT INTO books (id) VALUE(2);

INSERT INTO lend_history (id, book_id, lender_name) VALUES(1, 1, "mike");
INSERT INTO lend_history (id, book_id, lender_name) VALUES(2, 2, "jane");
INSERT INTO lend_history (id, book_id, lender_name) VALUES(3, 2, "ola");  /* this will be current lender */

INSERT INTO lend_current (lend_history_id) VALUES(3);

SELECT books.id, lend_history.lender_name FROM books
LEFT JOIN lend_history on lend_history.book_id=books.id
LEFT JOIN lend_current on lend_current.lend_history_id=lend_history.id
```

I want my query to lists all the books with the current lender's name but if nobody lent the book, it should still list that book with name field NULL.

this query lists the book with id (2) twice. But I want it to show only once with the current lender's name.

I tried with inner join, right join but couldn't achieve it. What am I missing?

I used to have "is_current" column in the lend_history before but after reading [Could I make a column in a table only allows one 'true' value and all other rows should be 'false'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228161/could-i-make-a-column-in-a-table-only-allows-one-true-value-and-all-other-rows) I decided to create a separate table for better practices.

Comment: 'this query lists the book with id (2) twice. But I want it to show only once with the current lender's name.' there isn't a current lender for book 2 in the data (only book 3)

Comment: Can you change the schema? I would add `book_id` to the `lend_current` table. Maybe also add `lender_name`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel and OP: I think handling of `is_current` field to create a new table is kind of over-normalization. I would have preferred to have just two tables (your original schema, with is_current = 0 depicting the current lender details); OR, you could have `current_lender_history_id` in the books table and store its value there or `NULL` if not lended. You can have FK then.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I agree with "current_lender_history_id in the books table". But `is_current = 0` kind of smells. I wouldn't like to ever update rows in a history table.

Comment: *" I would have preferred to have just two tables (your original schema, with is_current = 0 depicting the current lender details)"* @MadhurBhaiya using two separated tables to store lends in past of current would be called over-normalization... ideally one table  lend with a start and end date should be fine and when in doubt you can deploy partitions which you call current and history to separte logical on disk..  .

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think you got me wrong. I am not suggesting two separate history tables. I am suggesting just two tables, *viz.*, `books` and `lend_history` table. Now to determine which history row is current; we can have two ways: 1. Either have `is_current` field in the `lend_history` table (which will be **1** if current row); 2. Or, we can have a `current_history_id` field in the `books` table storing the id of current history row.

Comment: *" I think you got me wrong. I am not suggesting two separate history tables. I am suggesting just two tables"* @MadhurBhaiya in that case i know for sure i misinterpreted your comment.. But still a start and end date for a lend would make more sense to use to see if something is in the past or current..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have straight joins between the three tables, because of your handling of "is_current" column. One way would be to use [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (subquery); in the subquery, you can get all lend history items, which are "current". Now simply `LEFT JOIN` the subquery result to the books table:

```
SELECT b.id, dt.lender_name 
FROM books AS b 
LEFT JOIN 
( 
  SELECT lh.book_id, lh.lender_name
  FROM lend_current AS lc 
  JOIN lend_history AS lh ON lh.id = lc.lend_history_id
) AS dt ON dt.book_id = b.id
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6V9BQ21jrLfCd3G4mjNQPu/0)

**Result**

```
| id  | lender_name |
| --- | ----------- |
| 1   |             |
| 2   | ola         |
```

---

**Sidenote:** Instead of creating a third table, `lend_current`, I would have preferred to stick to your original schema of having two tables, `books`, and `lend_history`. Now to determine which history row is current, we can have two ways:

1. Your original approach: Either have `is_current` field in the lend_history table (which will be 1 if current row.
2. OR, We can have a `current_history_id` field in the `books` table storing the `id` of current history row. It will be `NULL` if the book is not being lent currently. This can also utilize Foreign Key constraint as well.

Comment: I couldn't create a unique constraint (book_id, is_current) when I had is_current. With the constraint, I aimed to have only one row for a book where is_current=True. Constraint failed when is_current was False many times. What would be the good approach for that?

Comment: @nurp Your original method has some limitations offcourse. Check the approach 2 in the **Sidenote** in my answer

Comment: I think with approach 2,  I have circular FK dependency problem. (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed.)
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @nurp It is not a circular FK error. Check your datatypes; both should be same. Please do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both the tables and share as a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: I let heidisql to create the code and it inserted lots of comment scripts. maybe FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 did the trick, I don't know yet but it works now. [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/of4ksCaY5TufXUSRZ2pBf7/0) Many thanks!

Comment: and this is the version without comment scripts: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oMJfcsKyn4mhoMSbApfNmC/0)