# Prisma, only one user's row can have "true" value, @@unique(userId, isActive)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I have a table with items, one user can have multiple items, but only one active at the same time. However, **@@unique** docs tells that all fields **must be not-null**, that means that user can have only two items: **one enabled and one disabled**.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228161/could-i-make-a-column-in-a-table-only-allows-one-true-value-and-all-other-rows) I saw that I need to create another table that contains **pointer to Item** and **isActive** value, but you cannot be sure that only one Item is enabled.

I don't want to use null values here, and postgres connector does not have composite constraints. Do you know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [solution you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228161/could-i-make-a-column-in-a-table-only-allows-one-true-value-and-all-other-rows) can be made to work:

> you cannot be sure that only one Item is enabled

You ***can*** be sure that only one Item is enabled by adding the unique constraint to that "TrueRow table with pointers": [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cQrGxUvF)

```sql
create table users(id int primary key);
insert into users values (1),(2);

create table test2(
  id int primary key,
  userid int not null references users(id), 
  misc text);

insert into test2 (id,userid,misc) values 
(1, 1, 'a'),
(2, 1, 'b'),
(3, 1, 'c');

create table true_row(
  fk_userid   int not null references users(id) unique,
  fk_test2_id int not null references test2(id) );

insert into true_row (fk_userid,fk_test2_id) values (1,3);
```

Now that the third entry is selected as the unique row where `isactive` would be `true`, the table won't allow "activating" another one:

```sql
insert into true_row (fk_userid,fk_test2_id) values (1,2);
--ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "true_row_fk_userid_key"
--DETAIL:  Key (fk_userid)=(1) already exists.
```

---

Normally, you can use a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gu18xiP_)

```sql
create table test(
  userid int, 
  isactive boolean,
  misc text);

create unique index my_partial_unique  
  on test (userid) 
  where isactive is true;
```

The `where` condition stops this index from constraining records with `isactive` set to `false` or `null`. It only applies when it's set to `true`, allowing only one such entry for each `userid`.

```sql
insert into test values 
   (1, false, 'a'),
   (1, false, 'b'),
   (1, true,  'c');

insert into test values 
   (1, true,  'd');
--ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_partial_unique"
--DETAIL:  Key (userid)=(1) already exists.

update test 
  set isactive=true 
  where userid=1 and misc='b';
--ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_partial_unique"
--DETAIL:  Key (userid)=(1) already exists.
```

Unfortunately, the feature ([#3076](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3076), [#6974](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6974)) isn't yet supported in Prisma, but you can [edit it into a migration](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6974#issuecomment-1527145264).